# Custom Font not working as Expected in xamrain forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am using font awesome or trying to in Xamarin forms. I was following this guide here.

https://medium.com/@tsjdevapps/use-fontawesome-in-a-xamarin-forms-app-2edf25311db4

But my button is being rendered wrong. Im just using the boiler app to test it working. I Download the font awesome cs as directed by the site

I placed the following into my app xaml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="LattestFeaturesXamarin.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" 
                x:Key="FontAwesomeBrands">
                <On Platform="Android" 
          Value="FontAwesome5FreeRegular.otf#Regular" />
                <On Platform="iOS" 
          Value="FontAwesome5FreeRegular" />
                <On Platform="UWP" 
          Value="/Assets/FontAwesome5Brands.otf#Font Awesome 5 Brands" />
            </OnPlatform>

            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" 
                x:Key="FontAwesomeSolid">
                <On Platform="Android" 
          Value="FontAwesome5FreeRegular.otf#Regular" />
                <On Platform="iOS" 
          Value="FontAwesome5FreeRegular" />
                <On Platform="UWP" 
          Value="/Assets/FontAwesome5Solid.otf#Font Awesome 5 Free" />
            </OnPlatform>

            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" 
                x:Key="FontAwesomeRegular">
                <On Platform="Android" 
          Value="FontAwesome5FreeRegular.otf#Regular" />
                <On Platform="iOS" 
          Value="FontAwesome5FreeRegular" />
                <On Platform="UWP" 
          Value="/Assets/FontAwesome5Regular.otf#Font Awesome 5 Free" />
            </OnPlatform>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

I have my fonts saved here and am using just the regular on ios and andriod for now so i can get this working.

You see here i have set it correct for android but yet you see im the simulator the button is not showing the correct font icon is it because i have not set the correct font face?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the Xamarin.Forms version?

Comment: @FilipePilettiPlucenio pleasse see edit and yes all expiermental flags have been set.

Comment: The Xamarin.Forms is up to date?

Comment: Could it work ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a key-value mismatch.Try to change your `Application.Resources` to below:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" 
            x:Key="FontAwesomeBrands">
            <On Platform="Android" 
      Value="FontAwesome5BrandsRegular.otf#Regular" />
            <On Platform="iOS" 
      Value="FontAwesome5BrandsRegular" />
            <On Platform="UWP" 
      Value="/Assets/FontAwesome5Brands.otf#Font Awesome 5 Brands" />
        </OnPlatform>

        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" 
            x:Key="FontAwesomeSolid">
            <On Platform="Android" 
      Value="FontAwesome5FreeSolid.otf#Regular" />
            <On Platform="iOS" 
      Value="FontAwesome5FreeSolid" />
            <On Platform="UWP" 
      Value="/Assets/FontAwesome5Solid.otf#Font Awesome 5 Free" />
        </OnPlatform>

        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" 
            x:Key="FontAwesomeRegular">
            <On Platform="Android" 
      Value="FontAwesome5FreeRegular.otf#Regular" />
            <On Platform="iOS" 
      Value="FontAwesome5FreeRegular" />
            <On Platform="UWP" 
      Value="/Assets/FontAwesome5Regular.otf#Font Awesome 5 Free" />
        </OnPlatform>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

and use like:

```
<Button Text="&#xf2b9;" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeRegular}">
```